# Display MATTRESS type icon in nest

Tags: types, icons

We always appreciate your cooperation.

Our custom device type 'action.devices.types.'MATTRESS' is displayed as a mattress-shaped icon in the Google Home app.
But in Nest, it's displayed unknown shape icon.

We hope that Nest will display the same shape as Google Home APP's icon.

Please tell me when you can apply.
Thank you.

We compared our custom type with the Google Home app and Nest